# Как включить ES6 синтаксис в webstorm?

Tags: javascript, webstorm

Webstorm подсвечивает стрелочные функции красным и пишет `Expression statement is not assignment or call`, что делать?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Нужно зайти в настройки (Ctrl+Alt+S)
открыть там
`Languages & Frameworks - Javascript`
и переключить
`Javascript language version`
на
`ECMAScript 6`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]