# цикл for, язык javascript

Tags: javascript

```
      for (var object of allow_countries) {
        console.log(Object.keys(object));
         }
```

Почему я не могу использовать этот цикл? почему ругается на var .. of?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В вопросе укажите название языка, вместо скриншота поместите в вопрос код, ошибку тоже нужно привести в печатный вид

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего ваш браузер его не поддерживает. `for of` появился в ES2015, который поддерживается пока ещё не всеми браузерами. К примеру всеми любимый IE о существовании этого цикла до сих пор не знает. Подробнее [тут](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)

Comment: у меня phpstorm ругается на синтаксис как я понимаю о_О

Comment: я хочу массив объектов перебрать

Comment: @Илья если дело только в PHPStorm, то скорее всего у него есть какая-то настройка, указывающая, какую версию языка поддерживать, и, вероятно, у вас эта опция не включает ES2015. Увы я не работал с этой IDE, поэтому не подскажу насчет того, где искать эту настройку

Answer (score -1):

Решил вот так:

```
  allow_countries.forEach(function (element, index) {
        console.log(element);
  });
```

Comment: Ну зачем отказываться от модного `for...of`, просто настрой в PhpStorm'е es6 синтаксис, как [советует](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/693226/227016) Darth.